# How to use regular expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
    empid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    jobtitle varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO emp 
VALUES ('Programmer'), ('VP'), ('DBA');
```

I tried using using the following but it does not work

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp
WHERE jobtitle LIKE '(PROG|VP)%';
```

Comment: Did you do *any* research?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. SQL Server doesn't support regular-expressions. Long-answer: you can via SQLCLR but only for on-prem servers and this wrecks performance as the queries aren't SARGable.

Comment: In this particular instance an index union might help: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES('PROG%','VP%')) v(Val) WHERE jobtitle LIKE Val)`. This is obvs not a good solution for the general case

Comment: Alternatively `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM emp JOIN (VALUES('PROG%','VP%')) v(Val) ON jobtitle LIKE v.Val`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not really have any regex support.  Your best bet here might be to use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE UPPER(jobtitle) LIKE 'PROG%' OR UPPER(jobtitle) LIKE 'VP%';
```

Comment: Is `UPPER` necessary given the default case-insensitive collation?

Comment: @Dai I just learned something; I had no idea the default collation were case insensitive (assuming your comment be correct).

Comment: 300K+ karma and you didn't know that? :O As far as I know, all implementations of SQL have used case-insensitive collation, going back to the 1970s.